# Decomposing a symmetric function into elementary symmetric polynomials.

Tags: permutations, symmetric-polynomials, elementary-functions, symmetric-functions, permutation-cycles

It is stated that any symmetric function can be expressed in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials. I am trying to do that for the following generating function:

\begin{equation}
\prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq k} (x_{i} + x_{j}).
\end{equation}

I can't quite seem to find a way to do this in general. I can see some kind of pattern though, involving the monomial symmetric functions, which are

\begin{equation}
m_{(1,2)} = x_1 x_2^2 + x_1^2 x_2,
\end{equation}
and similarly for any $k$. The subscripted values in $m$ can be any integer.

I've shown that this can be done for the cases $k=1,2$ in which cases we get

\begin{equation}
\prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq 2} (x_{i} + x_{j}) = (x_1 + x_2) = \frac{m_{(1,2)}}{\sigma_2^{(2)}},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq 3} (x_{i} + x_{j}) = \frac{m_{(1,2,3)}}{\sigma_3^{(3)}} + 2 \sigma_3^{(3)},
\end{equation}
and for $k=4$ I get something in the form of
\begin{equation}
\prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq 4} (x_{i} + x_{j}) = \frac{m_{(1,2,3,4)}}{\sigma_4^{(4)}} + ?,
\end{equation}
which I cannot work out, at least not easily, though I will do the tedious calculation. (Is there a way to employ the monomial symmetric functions in mathematica somehow?)

Main question, is there already a known decomposition to this generating function? If so, what is it? If not, how should I go about making one? Or at least being able to determine it for values up to $k=6$.

Comment: What range of $k$ are you interested in? $k \geq 1$?

Comment: Yes, I'd like $k=1,2,3$ at least, but it'd also be nice to have a general solution.

Comment: Neglect the last comment. I now see you have a strictly greater than sign.

Comment: Oops! I think I know what caused the confusion, I fixed the typo. Transitioning between a german and english keyboards isn't the easiest!

Comment: Haha--no problem!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out a very similar question has been answered quite nicely here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2403583/653042

I guess I should either delete my original question now, or make it more focused on the monomial symmetric functions instead...?

Comment: You don't need to delete it. I'll vote to close it as a duplicate and the link you give will be posted at the top. You can also keep this answer as another place where the link is documented.

Comment: Ok, perfect, thanks!