# Number of terms of the polynomial $\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}( x_{i}+x_{j})$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, graph-theory, trees, symmetric-polynomials

The number of terms of the polynomial:

$$\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\left(  x_{i}+x_{j}\right)$$

coincides for $n=2,3,4,5,6$ with the sequence [OEIS A001858](https://oeis.org/A001858). One of the things it counts is the number of forests of trees on $n$ labeled nodes.

I tried to check some of the references at the OEIS page but up to now I haven't found any reference to the above polynomial.

I have found also some ways of expressing the polynomial [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2403583/573047) but I am not sure it can help here.

Any hint for proving that the OEIS sequence counts also the number of terms of the above polynomial for any $n \ge 2$?

Comment: If we let $a_n$ be the number of terms of $\prod_{i<j}(x_i+x_j)$, then it is directly true that $a_n$ is the number of score sequences of a directed tournament. This paper gives a bijection between score sequences and forests: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579176